# Plot3D is incorrectly returning "1/0. encountered"

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.**

---

The line of code

```
Plot3D[1/y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, x + 1, x + 2}]
```

is returning several "Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered." error messages, and then returning an empty plot.  But the function does not diverge on the region to be plotted.  Why is this?  I am running Mathematica 10.2.0.0 on Mac OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5.

Comment: Can't comment on why it tries to evaluate `y` at 0, but here's a workaround. Instead of `1/y` use `Piecewise[{{0, y == 0}, {1/y, True}}]`.

Comment: @march That does it!

Comment: I can reproduce, and I strongly suspect this is a bug. Extra weird is that I decided to take a look at it in the debugger; when I ran without the debugger I got three Power::infy messages, followed by a General::stop, and then an empty plot appeared. When I ran with the debugger and had it break on messages, I got *two* Power::infy messages (one after I told it to keep stepping) and then the plot appears normally. This is truly one for the department of mysterious effects.

Comment: Wolfram Technical Support contacted  Support case with the identification **[CASE:3445899]** was created.

Comment: @march - Your workaround can be shortened to `Piecewise[{{0, y == 0}}, 1/y]`.

Comment: @rhermans. So, add the `bugs` tag?

Comment: I think the only bug here is that it tries to do anything in the first place.

Comment: @QuantumDot I see you edited this to say that the bug persists in version 11.0, but my version 11.0 is no longer giving the error.  Does yours?

Comment: Yes it does on machine Mac OSX 10.11

Comment: It gives 1/0 errors on my other machine Mac OSX 10.10 as well.

Comment: @QuantumDot Very strange; it works correctly on my Mac OS X 10.10.

Comment: This is still buggy for me in 11.0.1.

Comment: The error messages have reappeared in 11.0.1, but it still plots correctly.  I have filed a report with Wolfram.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The problem is also present in Mma v 9.0.1 to 10.3 in Windows.
>
> *Wolfram Technical Support* contacted.
> Support case with the identification **[CASE:3445899]** was created.

This does not solve the problem, just adds to the diagnostics.

The function get evaluated symbolically and at `{0.0000715,0.}` before starting to canvas the `PlotRange`.

```
f[x_, y_] := Block[{},
  If[
   Not[NumberQ[x]]
    || Not[NumberQ[y]]
    || Not[0 <= x <= 1]
    || Not[1 < y < 3]
   , Print[{x, y}]
   ];
  x]

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, x + 1, x + 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Not just there ... `Reap@Plot3D[(Sow[{x, y}]; 1/y), {x, 0, 1}, {y, x + 1, x + 2}]`

Comment: Ahh.. so  elegant...

Answer (score 11):

The best approach for plotting over non-rectagular domains is to use the regions form of `Plot3D`:

```
 Plot3D[1/y, Element[{x,y}, Parallelogram[{0,1},{{1,1},{0,1}}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can also be written as `Plot3D[1/y, Element[{x, y}, ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && x + 1 <= y <= x + 2, {x, y}]]]`

Comment: Right. There are a number of forms you could use for this particular region. More importantly, there are lots of regions that can't be cast into the traditional `{var, min, max}` form, but that can be cast as some form of region.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram said "The syntax for Plot3D that you are using is undocumented (even though similar syntax for functions like Table or NIntegrate is documented), and is thus not yet expected to work consistently."